# Fourier transform of a sinc function in python

Tags: python, fft

I wanted to know how to plot the Fourier transform of a sin function. From theory, I expect to see a rect function or something that looks like a top hat function. I have defined a set of "x" points with numpy's linspace and have correspondingly calculated np.sinc for each of the x values. I could then easily plot this to showcase a simple sin function centered at x=0.

I then used scipy.fftpack.fft to compute the Fourier transform of the sinc value array and attempted to plot these results expecting to see a rect or top hat function. Instead I obtain the plot shown below.

sinc function and its Fourier transform plots:

[image: sinc function and its Fourier transform plots]

Im not sure why this happens and what I can do to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but here's an answer anyway:

Yes, from theory you'd expect to see a rect-function. However, the output of `fft` differs from the original (continuous) Fourier transform in several ways, see also the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html) (NumPy, but the algorithm is the same as `scipy.fftpack.fft` as far as I'm aware), so you'll need to take a few additional steps to get your expected output.

To start with, some code to (approximately) reproduce your plots:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define a time axis, plus some useful parameters
N = 500
t_start, t_end = -12.5, 12.5

t = np.linspace(t_start, t_end, N, endpoint = False)

dt = (t_end - t_start)/N
fs = 1/dt # sampling frequency
fN = fs/2 # Nyquist frequency

# The sinc function (note that NumPy uses the normalised sinc,
# defined as sin(pi*t)/(pi*t))
f = np.sinc(t)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, f)

# The FFT
F = np.fft.fft(f)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.real(F))
# Not sure how you produced your fft plot; just plotting F issues a warning
# and discards the complex part of F, resulting in the same plot as above.
```

**Problem 1: Output is shifted**

Quoting from the NumPy FFT documentation: The values in the result follow so-called “standard” order: If `A = fft(a, n)`, then `A[0]` contains the zero-frequency term (the sum of the signal), which is always purely real for real inputs. Then `A[1:n/2]` contains the positive-frequency terms, and `A[n/2+1:]` contains the negative-frequency terms, in order of decreasingly negative frequency. For an even number of input points, `A[n/2]` represents both positive and negative Nyquist frequency, and is also purely real for real input. For an odd number of input points, `A[(n-1)/2]` contains the largest positive frequency, while `A[(n+1)/2]` contains the largest negative frequency. The routine `np.fft.fftfreq(n)` returns an array giving the frequencies of corresponding elements in the output. The routine `np.fft.fftshift(A)` shifts transforms and their frequencies to put the zero-frequency components in the middle, and `np.fft.ifftshift(A)` undoes that shift.

And no, the discrete Fourier transform doesn't *really* include negative frequencies, but thinking of it this way is nice for comparing with the continuous version (and perfectly acceptable, because DFT is periodic).

```py
# use fftshift to centre output at zero frequency
F_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(F)
# use fftfreq to get frequency axis
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(N, dt)
freq_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(freq)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq_shifted, np.real(F_shifted))
```

**Problem 2: Output oscillates**

Thanks to @Cris Luengo for this explanation: This is because `fft` expects a periodic input signal, with its origin (t = 0) in the first element. Having the origin halfway, at `N/2` will give the Fourier transform of a delayed sinc, which is phase shifted with respect to the Fourier transform of a sinc (i.e. multiplied by a complex exponential; shift theorem). In the DFT case, this works out as a complex exponential oscillating at the Nyquist frequency (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)). The magnitude of this complex exponential is 1 (energy in spectrum isn't changed), so if you'd plot the absolute value of your output, there won't be any oscillations. However, the proper solution is to shift your input signal to have its origin in the first element.

```py
# Plot absolute value of F_shifted, oscillations will have disappeared
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq_shifted, abs(F_shifted))

# Shift input signal before applying fft
f_shifted = np.fft.ifftshift(f)
# Determine FFT and shift output
F = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(f_shifted))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq_shifted, np.real(F))
```

**Problem 3: Output amplitude is off**

See the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976162): to get the correct amplitude, you need to scale the output by the time step.

```py
# Scale output
F_scaled = dt*F

plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq_shifted, np.real(F_scaled))
```

And finally, the oscillations that remain around the "corners" of your output are a result of the rect function being discontinuous there. To properly capture these discontinuities, you'd need an infinite number of frequencies. The `fft` algorithm only includes frequencies up to the Nyquist frequency, hence the oscillations (called Gibbs phenomenon).